# Factorisations of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I'm actually in a course of Abstract Algebra, and the teacher asked some interesting questions at the end of a course on the material we had seen. I found the answer to the first question, but the other two leave me perplexed. Could you give me your opinion on the questions (2) and (3)?

**(1)** Is the function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ such that $$f= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & ...\\
f(1) & f(2) & f(3) & f(4) & ...
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & ...\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & ...
\end{pmatrix}$$ is a permutation?
Answer : no, because $1$ isn't an element in the image.

**(2)** Is there a function $ f \in S_E$  that is factorisable into disjoint cycle of infinite order such that $\mid \{n \in \mathbb{N} : f(n) \not= n\}\mid < \infty$ ?

**Definitions :**

1. $S_E$ is the set of all permutation of E.
2. Let the set $E \not= \emptyset$. W say that a map $f : E \to E$ has an inverse function, if there is a mapping $g : E \to E$ such that both composition $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are the application identity for each $x$ element of $E$. We say that $f$ is a permutation (bijection) of $E$ .

**(3)** Does the subset of functions $\in S_{\mathbb{N}}$ ($S_E$ with $E=\mathbb{N}$) consistent with $\mid \{n \in \mathbb{N} : f(n) \not= n\}\mid < \infty$ form a group?

Comment: (2) The identity permutation is factorizable into disjoint cycles of infinite order, namely into $0$ such cycles. Barring this sort of nitpicking, the answer is "No". Think about it: An cycle of infinite order must move (= not fix) infinitely many numbers. Composing it with *disjoint* cycles does not change anything about this.

Comment: (3) You mean the permutations that move only finitely many numbers? Yes, they form a group.

Comment: Why is it a group?

Comment: Show that the identity is such a permutation; that the composition of two such permutations is such a permutation; that the inverse of any such permutation is such a permutation. None of these is difficult.

Comment: Are you able to rigorously prove (2)? The argument seems logical, but I don't grasp 100% why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(2)**
$$
\underbrace{\cdots \mapsto 6 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 2}_\text{even} \mapsto \underbrace{1 \mapsto 3\mapsto 5\mapsto \cdots}_\text{odd}
$$
$$
n\mapsto \begin{cases}
n-2 & \text{if $n$ is even and $n\ne 2$}, \\
1 & \text{if }n=2, \\
n+2 & \text{if $n$ is odd.}
\end{cases}
$$
**(3)** If $f$ and $g$ move only finitely many numbers, then so does $f\circ g$.  Consider the intersection of the set of all fixed points of $f$ and the set of all fixed points of $g$.  That is the set of all numbers fixed by both $f$ and $g$.  Only finitely many numbers are not among these because the intersection of the complements of two finite sets is the complement of the union of the two finite sets, and the union of two finite sets is finite.  If $f$ moves only finitely many numbers, then so does $f^{-1}$.  Can you prove this last statement?  Then can you see that the two assertions here are all you need?

Comment: The function that you provided is not that $\mid \{n \in \mathbb{N} : f(n) \not= n\}\mid = \infty$?

Comment: Can you show how this function meets the assumption of the question?